# count of flags in a column after pivoting the table

Tags: oracle, return-value

I have created a function that pivots my current table so that I can see which of my students enjoy what sports. I am using oracle db. So now, each sport is in its own respective column after the pivoting. It is flagged as a 1 if a student enjoys that specific sport.

```
    Year    Student    Basketball    Baseball    Golf    Soccer   
    2019    Michael         1           NA         1        NA
    2018    Jason           NA          NA         1        NA
    2017    Sarah           1           1          1        NA
    2016    Michelle        NA          NA         NA       NA
```

I want to grab the count for the sports columns to see how many students flagged that respective sport.

```
select 
   SUM(CASE WHEN Basketball=1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as NBA,
   SUM(CASE WHEN Baseball=1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as MLB,
   SUM(CASE WHEN Golf=1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as PGA,
   SUM(CASE WHEN Soccer=1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as MLS
from students_sports
group by year
order by 1;
```

I have tried the syntax above but no luck. I have also tried the syntax below.

```
select 
    sum(nvl("Basketball", 0)) as NBA,
    sum(nvl("Baseball", 0)) as MLB,
    etc....
```

When I run this query, I get the total count of rows and not the actual sum count of the rows flagged as 1. Any thoughts?

Comment: got ya missed that one. thanks

Comment: there's no problem with your first query provided you add `student` column to `select` and `group by` list

Answer (score 2):

the first syntax is wrong. Your column `Basketball, Baseball, Golf, Soccer` is varchar as you are saving NA in the field not numeric. And while you are doing a comparison in a query `CASE WHEN Basketball=1` you are doing a numeric comparison. So change your query as following and let us know if it works.

```
**Query**  
`SELECT SUM (CASE WHEN Basketball = '1' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS NBA
      ,SUM (CASE WHEN Baseball = '1' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)   AS MLB
      ,SUM (CASE WHEN Golf = '1' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)       AS PGA
      ,SUM (CASE WHEN Soccer = '1' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)     AS MLS
FROM students_sports
GROUP BY year
ORDER BY 1;`
```

**Example:**
https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=9c6cc6b067cc128b699316cb299769e3

```
This should give you result as 1 or 0. Let us know how it goes. I am not sure about your SUM what are you doing with it but it does not make sense to me as that sum will worth nothing.
```

Comment: You are correct, it is a varchar so I should be using single quotes. The query runs and outputs but I am getting 0's all around for all my years. The sum part is to sum up the count of each row item so that I know how many votes were casted to the sports column. Hope this makes sense.

Comment: Can you update the data (input) and your expected output. I will rewrite the query for you and will explain why and what was wrong with your query. Because in current data it is unsure that 1 in your data is just one student voted or someone voted for that column. So, add realistic scenario you are expecting and I will update answer accordingly.

Comment: For example, I only can see data for Michael in 2019, Jaosn in 2018. So Michael liked Basketball so in 2019 you will only have one person. Or show us original data, before pivoting and expected output.